# Are words ending in -ly adverbs?

Tags: adverbs, suffixes

Adverbs [often end in -ly](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/61/55). But the word *friendly* is not an adverb, is it? *A friendly advice* is [incorrect](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/103619/21009), but *a friendly person* is correct. Is the word *friendly* very unusual or are there many non-adverbs ending in -ly?

Comment: Lots of words end in *-ly*, including nouns like *panoply* and *butterfly* and *belly*, verbs like *dally* and *comply* and *imply*, and even injections like *golly*.  Then you have words like *fly*, which can be any of a noun, verb, or adjective, but not an adverb.

Comment: I'm surprised that there was no one to point out that while ***a** friendly advice* is incorrect, but there is nothing wrong with *friendly advice*. And that is my friendly advice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is fundamentally a historical question, and if asked on ELU would deserve a very long and interesting answer. Here I will offer only so much history as might help a learner avoid confusion.

The *-ly* ending on adjectives descends from an Old English suffix *-lic* which was very often employed to turn a noun into an adjective. Consequently there are many adjectives today which have the *-ly* suffix: *manly, womanly, daily, kingly, cowardly*, to name only a very few in addition to your *friendly*.

This use declined in Early Modern English, and today it is no longer ‘productive’—that is, we no longer employ the ending to create adjectives. (Today we mostly use the *-ish* or *-like* or *-y* suffixes, or just use the bare noun as an adjective, or create an adjective from Greek or Latin roots.)

The *-ly* ending on adverbs descends from a very similar OE suffix *-lice*. When the adjective *-ly* fell into disuse, the adverbial *-ly* had the field to itself. Well into EModE, however, it was more usual to use the unmodified adjective in an adverbial sense. In the 17th and 18th century, however, there was a strong movement towards rationalizing the written language; and at this time the *-ly* ending became what it is today, the standard and almost universal way of distinguishing an adverb from its corresponding adjective.

Comment: Then you have pairs of adjectives like *kind* and *kindly*, or *good* and *goodly*. Also, I’m not sure I am wholly convinced that *-ly* is no longer productive: can one no longer comport oneself in a gentlemanly manner?  Ok, fine: firemen cannot behave in a firemanly way, can they now? Curious.

Comment: @tchrist  *kind* is originally a noun, and *OED 1* believes *goodly* to be formed on the noun. *Gentlemanly* goes back to LME; I imagine it endured in part because of a perceived construction as *gentle* + *manly*.

Answer (score 3):

Words ending in -ly can be adjectives and adverbs, although -ly is better known as an adverb suffix.

Yes, *friendly* is an adjective formed from the noun *friend*, but you cannot convert *friendly* in an adverb adding another -ly: **friendlyly*.

So, you have to use *friendly* in both cases.

Other adjectives ending in -ly could be, for example, *lovely* or *scholarly*.

(Ref. English Grammar Today - Cambridge)

Answer (score 0):

*-ly* is the suffix used to form adjectives, and adverbs from adjectives.

In the first case, the adjectives have two meanings:

- having the quality of (*brotherly*)
- recurring at intervals of (*hourly*, *quarterly*)

As far as I know, *friendly advice* is correct: *Friendly* is also an adjective and, as in *friendly person*, it is followed by a noun. *Friendly* can be used as adverb, at least in American English; alternatively, *friendlily* is  adverb too.
In British English, *friendly* is adjective, and noun; the adverb is *friendlily*.

Comment: Could you please give an example using *friendly* as an adverb?

Comment: _She friendly poked his shoulder._ Is that a bad example?

Comment: I don’t now whether it is a “bad” example, but it is not one I am familiar with. I could not say it. Do people say that?

Comment: @tchrist,kiamlaluno: I don't think there is a "current" one-word adjectival form of *friendly*. You could try getting away with [friendlily](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=friendlily&year_start=1930&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) - but as that chart shows, the usage hasn't made (or more properly, *kept*) many friends in recent decades.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is in British English; American English uses _friendly_ as adverb too, but not as noun. (At least, that is what I have been taught from a friend of mine.)

Comment: @kiamlaluno: America's a big country, so even if the percentage of speakers who use *friendly* adverbially is the same as in Britain, there would be numerically more of them. I can't say for sure, but it seems unlikely to me Americans would be hanging on to **friendlily**, which is largely a dated/archaic form, more than Brits. The NGram in my previous link offers no support for that proposition, and OED mentions no US/UK divide. But that doesn't imply we need to use the adjective as an adverb.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My comment was for your "I don't think there is a 'current' one-word adjectival form of _friendly_." The "Shorter Oxford English Dictionary" I have reports _friendly_ as adverb meaning "in a friendly manner or spirit, friendlily." The NOAD reports also that use, and the OED reports also _friendly_ used as noun.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I put the word "current" in quotes to indicate that I'm using it somewhat loosely. I believe most native speakers today don't use "friendly" adverbially, nor do they use "friendlily" at all. They find various alternatives to avoid the problem, such as [{he} asked friendly-like](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22asked+friendly-like%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: MW online shows [_friendlily_ & _friendly_](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/friendlily) as adverbs. It's not common to read or hear the former, & usually the latter is coupled with _-like_ (as FumbleFingers says) or something like "_in as friendly a way as I can_" or "_in a friendly {way/manner}_".

Comment: Right; “friendly advice” is correct, but “a[n] advice” is incorrect.  This should probably be a separate question, but, for example, “an advice” is like “a happiness” or “a money”.  The singular is most often phrased as “a piece of advice”.