# Is this an adjective or a noun?

Tags: adverbs, secondary-predicates

> (1) Dotted here and there among the students, the ghosts shone **misty
>   silver**.
>  (2) Then the hat twitched. A rip near the brim opened
>   **wide** like a mouth - and the hat began to sing:
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Is the ‘misty silver’ a predicative adjective that denote the result of the intransitive verb like in the second example? Or is it an object of the transitive verb?

Comment: This [question on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/102666/24489), and especially Edwin Ashworth's answer, may be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, dear. This sort of thing is where ordinary part-of-speech and sentence-constituent analysis gets very iffy.

The actual meaning is perfectly clear:

> The ghosts shone *in such a manner that they looked* misty silver.
>   The rip opened like a mouth. *The opening was wide*.

If you like to call the pair of adjectives *misty silver* (in which *misty* modifies *silver*) a **secondary complement**, that's cool; it gives you a name which tells you how it works.

But you can't do that with *wide*, because *wide* taken as an adjective wouldn't modify an entity present in the sentence, *rip* or *mouth*, but the implicit opening created. This is just how *wide* works. The simplest way of analyzing it is as an adverb on *open*; that's how [*OED*](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdictio102murruoft#page/110/mode/2up) treats it. It's very old in that sense, like *hard*, predating the [practice of forming adverbs with the *-ly* suffix](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/1345/32); and also like *hard* it has a doublet which *does* have the *-ly* suffix and which bears a slightly different meaning.