# Confusion about adjunct and complement

Tags: adjuncts, secondary-predicates

In my recently concluded test, I was asked to identify the sentence pattern of this sentence:

> It stands tall

I split it as:

```
It | stands | tall

S      V       A
```

For me, "tall" is an additional information and if removed, the sentence still makes sense to *me*.

However, my teacher marked it wrong and said that it should instead be C (complement)

Can anyone help me out? Was I wrong or was she?

Also please be simple as I don't know many technical terms except *the* basic ones. I say this because I went through the link that StoneyB provided, and wasn't able to understand terms like "secondary complement", "sentence-constituent". I know I may be the noobest person around here, so please explain those terms if you use it.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Amit Joki. I believe you will find an answer at [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/6075/32) (note particularly the [ELU.se] answer linked in the comment there; but I am not suggesting this question be closed, because your terminology is somewhat different than either the question or the answer there.

Comment: @StoneyB check out my edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are both right, and you are both wrong!

- **You** are right in that the word *tall* does not play a syntactic role which cannot be omitted. *It stands* is a **comple**te sentence; *stand* does not require a following adjective or adjectival to **comple**te its meaning, which is what the grammatical term ***comple**ment* ordinarily means.
- **Your teacher** is right in that the word *tall* is not used either as an attributive adjective directly modifying *it* or as an adverb modifying *stand*, which are the traditional roles played by adjuncts: it is a predicate adjective describing the subject, exactly as in the sentence *It **is** tall*. Grammarians therefore often find it useful to describe uses of this sort as *secondary predication* or *secondary complementation*, as if the verb were behaving like a linking verb like *BE* or *BECOME*.
- You are **both** wrong in that the collocation *stand tall* is an *idiom*: it has, or can have, a meaning which is not entirely understandable as the sum of its components. *Stand tall* in many contexts has the figurative meaning “to exhibit pride or defiance”; for instance, in this headline from *The Guardian*:

  > **On the day of his release, Nelson Mandela stood tall** ... *and the story goes on to speak of the “iconic image of that moment – a lean, beaming Mandela in a dark suit emerging from Victor Verster prison holding hands with Winnie, both raising triumphant clenched fist salutes”.*

  From this perspective *stand tall* is a single entity which cannot be analyzed into different parts with different roles.

The lesson to be drawn from this is not that you guys are wrong and I am right; it is that **all of us are right**.

- You have brought a sophisticated understanding of the term *adjunct* to the discussion—perhaps more sophisticated than your teacher expected!
- Your teacher, on the other hand, is concerned that you gain a more sophisticated understanding of the term *complement*, and is trying to ascertain whether you have mastered that.
- And I am bringing an entirely different perspective into the discussion with the term *idiom*, for the sake of completeness.

The point is that grammatical terms like *adjunct* and *complement* and *idiom* are not real “things” but *tools* for talking about language and understanding how it works. Which tool you use depends on what you want to talk about, just as you use a screwdriver for some jobs and a chisel for others.

Comment: @AmitJoki Is this clear? If you have any trouble with it, please say so and I will rewrite.

Comment: yeah this is crystal clear! BTW, we aren't native speakers of English and usually don't go deep to the level of *idioms* ;)

Comment: @AmitJoki As we say, "You have to walk before you can run". By the way, you are fortunate; few US students have teachers who work with such sophisticated grammar.

Comment: @AmitJoki That's what we're here for! ... But please, don't fight with your teacher ... if the teacher is good, you should collaborate, and if the teacher is bad you always lose. And in any case, the teacher is trying to get you through the exams, which is not always the same thing as understanding the language.

Comment: StoneyB, does "All" in "All the cows have been milked" come under adjunct?

Comment: BTW, when I said "fighting", I was actually referring to debate which was in a good sense (both of us were cooperating) `;)`

Comment: @AmitJoki No: there it is a *determiner* —specifically, a *quantifier*. You may look up those two terms on Wikipedia if you are not familiar with them; you may also consult the Wikipedia article on ‘English Determiners’.

Comment: StoneyB, thanks. I'm feeling this site just rocks, as I come from Stack Overflow background where these kind of comments are flagged as "not too constructive" `;)`

Comment: @AmitJoki Well, SO is on a vastly larger scale, with a very different subject matter and a very different audience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15255/discussion-between-amit-joki-and-stoneyb).

Comment: This is an excellent answer.