# Adjectives with and without -ly

Tags: adjectives, suffixes

Are there adjectives in English that are still adjectives when adding *-ly* to it?

More precisely, I mean words that would be originally adjectives, and that would still be adjectives when adding the *-ly* suffix to it (even if the meaning is different).

For example, *elderly* is, as *elder* can be used as an adjective. *Lone* is as well. Are there others?

(I have read [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1341/are-words-ending-in-ly-adverbs) but it is asking about whether there are nouns that turn into adjectives (as opposed to adverbs) when you add *-ly*. I'm asking about whether there are **adjectives** that remain adjectives after adding *-ly*.)

Comment: Hmm this question focuses on nouns, while I'm rather asking for adjectives

Comment: But *elder* and *good* also act as nouns, and is on the nominal sense that the *-ly* forms are built.

Comment: @servabat If the answers to the linked question do not answer your question to your satisfaction, you can [edit] your question to explain why. If you don't do so, your question is at risk of being closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @starsplusplus : well I had a satisfying enough answer (in that post), should I still edit it?

Comment: @starsplusplus : I meant, the answer on this question, not on the linked one.

Comment: Did the other question's answers answer yours? Having an answer on this question doesn't change what I said [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43275/adjectives-in-ly?noredirect=1#comment80521_43275).

Comment: @starsplusplus : it did not

Comment: @starsplusplus : ok, but I had my answer, should I still edit it? I mean I don't really care if it get closed as I had a answer (on this post, and I even validated it) but would should I still do it?

Comment: Yes, you should still do it. It will help future visitors who may have the same question as you. Also, if you get too many questions closed, the system can block your ability to post new questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'elder' *is* an adjective! I can say 'This is my elder/eldest sister' at any age (though I would say 'older/oldest'). Adding 'ly' changes the distribution - we can only say 'My sister is elderly' (not true in my case).
Two more that I've found after brief research are 'lone' ('This is the lone ranger' v 'This is the lonely ranger' v 'The ranger is lonely' but *'The ranger is lone') and 'live' ('a live television show' v 'a lively television show' v 'the television show was live' v 'the television show was lively').

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking to coward, is that correct?

Comment: 'Coward' is a noun. Even if we say 'This is my coward brother', it's still a noun, even thought it's modifying another noun.